# iOS Charts: Adding fill color below a line in Version 4

Tags: ios-charts

I am updating to [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) version 4. Adding the fill color below a line in a line chart seems to have changed because I get the error:

The old approach that worked for me...

```
userTotalEmissionsDataSet.fill = Fill(CGColor: colorLight.cgColor)
```

...now gives this error --> `'any Fill' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

What is the new approach? Thanks!

Context:

```
let userVehicleDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: userVehicleEmissionsChartDataArray)
    userVehicleDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    userVehicleDataSet.mode = .linear
    userVehicleDataSet.setColor(colorVehicleTravel)
    xc
    userVehicleDataSet.fillAlpha = 1.0
    userVehicleDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .fillColor and not .fill

```
dataSet.fillColor = yourColor
```